# Undefined values in Kendo-ui combobox

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui

I have implement combobox using kendo,but while loading data it always show undefine.I am using open event of comboBox and manually load data.Below is my code snippet.So am I missing anything to load data?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<input id="combobox" />
<script>
  var placeHolder="select..";
  var data=[];
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({index: 0,
          minLength: 1,
          filter: "contains",
          dataTextField: "name",
          dataValueField: "id",
          ignoreCase: true,
          autoBind: false,
         open: function(e){
            e.sender.dataSource.read()
          },
          dataSource: {
            data: [],
            autoSync: false,
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: function (o) {

                var dataResolve = [];

                
                  dataResolve.push("A");
                data=dataResolve;
                o.success(data);
              }
            }
          }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your transport.read you are replacing potential response data in 'o' with an array having one item "A". Also, the `data` variable is accessing the nearest closure (global?) because it is not scope restricted by `var` or `let` declaration.

Your code

```
            var dataResolve = [];
            dataResolve.push("A");
            data=dataResolve;
            o.success(data);
```

This does not align with the expectation that the array items will be objects with fields named "name" and "id" as specified in the combobox configuration.

Not sure what you specifically trying to do, but to inject your own data in read, try using just this:

```
                o.success([
                  {name:"Bhautik", id: 1},
                ]);
```

The data source is not configured to be connected to any remote server, but when it is you might find you want to use `dataBound` event if you plan to 'tweak' the data response.  If you are not going to use remote data just put the items in the dataSource.data configuration array and don't do serverFiltering.

Comment: Actually i dont know what is the use of  "o.success"

Comment: It's use is a callback to the datasource indicating the read was successful and passes the data obtained to the data source, the data source in turn updates everything that is listening to it, in your case the combobox component.  The component is listening for changes in the data source and modifies the elements it renders, such as the drop down item list.  Read more at the docs: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.read

Answer (score 0):

You have mention dateTextField as "Name" and dateValueField as "Id" therefore you will have to assign name with array like this.

```
   dataResolve.push({name:"A", id: 1});
```

Try this :

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<input id="combobox" />
<script>
  var placeHolder="select..";
  var data=[];
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({index: 0,
          minLength: 1,
          filter: "contains",
          dataTextField: "name",
          dataValueField: "id",
          ignoreCase: true,
          autoBind: false,
         open: function(e){
            e.sender.dataSource.read()
          },
          dataSource: {
            data: [],
            autoSync: false,
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: function (o) {

                var dataResolve = [];

                
                  dataResolve.push({name:"A", id: 1});
                data=dataResolve;
                o.success(data);
              }
            }
          }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
 Run code snippetReturn to post
```